# Find tables and columns that are in use and filled

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to migrate a legacy SQL Server database to the dynamics365 dataverse. This is an extensive database with over 1,500 tables and 10,000+ columns.
The query below gives me the tables and columns of tables with a positive rowcount but I would also like to eliminate the empty columns So I get a list of tables and columns that need to be considered.

Any ideas anybody? All help is appreciated.

```
SELECT tb.name
    , c.name
    , tp.name as type_name
    , c.max_length
    , c.precision
    , c.column_id
FROM sys.columns c 
join sys.tables tb on tb.object_id = c.object_id
JOIN sys.types tp ON c.user_type_id = tp.user_type_id 
WHERE 1=1
and exists (
    select par.object_id
    from sys.partitions par
    where par.object_id = c.object_id
    and par.rows >= 1
)
order by tb.name, c.column_id;
```

Comment: You'll need to use dynamic SQL to do this; there are solutions out there that do this , but generally such tasks are an [XY Problem](//XYproblem.info) in my experience.

Comment: Also, just because a column only has `NULL` values now doesn't mean it won't, and removing said column could break your application.

Comment: Optimizations, like removing unused tables and/or columns, should be done after migration, not during migration.